# Jupyter notebook setup in VS Code was working fine; now get "Running cells with 'Python 3.9.12 64-bit' requires ipykernel package."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a python project (folder) that I'm working on in VS Code (in Windows) and it uses Jupyter notebook. The project uses a virtual env. It was working fine a few days ago. Today when I open up one of the .ipynb files in the project, I see:

> Running cells with 'Python 3.9.12 64-bit' requires ipykernel package.
> Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python
> environment.  Command:
> 'c:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe -m
> pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

I don't understand why VS Code is looking at the system installation of python. I have the following in settings.json in the .vscode subfolder of this project:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "proj_env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
}
```

And in the virtual environment for this project, I have confirmed I have ipykernel installed. It was working fine a few days ago. I see that ipykernel was updated 10/31/2022, so just to try it, I updated the ipykernel package in the virtual env from 6.15.2 to 6.17.0.

But clearly for some reason VS Code is looking to the system installation of python instead of the virtual env.

Pulling my hair out because I changed nothing in the past few days. In fact I just opened the project today for the first time since a few days ago when it was working fine.

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+P to select python interpreter, the virtual env python interpreter is already selected. But I still see the warning posted above re: ipykernel package needing to be installed.

[image: screenshot]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the warning has told you how to solve it: `c：/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall`

Comment: that looks like it will install ipykernel to the system installation of python. I don't want ipykernel installed there. It's already installed in the virtual environment for this project.

Comment: In the upper right corner of the ipynb file, you can select the kernel. Did you choose the virtual environment?

Comment: That was part of the solution. Very confusing that VS Code uses one python interpreter for .py files and terminal and a different python interpreter for Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) files. The kernel I wanted wasn't there, and it was using the system installation of python, which is why I was getting this message, while the virtual env python was being used for .py and terminal in the same project, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt at an explanation of the solution. I'm sure someone understands this better and can explain it better (please do and I will pick your answer as the solution!):

VS Code uses one python interpreter for .py files and terminal and a different python interpreter for Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) files. The kernel I wanted wasn't there, and it was using the system installation of python, which is why I was getting this message (ipykernel not installed to system environment, and I don't want it there), while the virtual env python (which has ipykernel) was being used for .py and terminal in the same project, hence the confusion.

To 'install' the kernel for Jupyter, I activated the virtual env in VS Code powershell terminal. Then ran:

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=project_name`

Then exit VS Code, restart, open project folder and in upper right corner of Jupyter notebook, use the kernel picker to select the kernel. The kernel I just created wasn't there, so I used CTRL+SHIFT+P in VS Code, then type Jupyter: Filter Kernels, and there I could see the kernel I created, and it was checked, then went back to kernel picker and was able to select the correct kernel.

So now the .ipynb code has access to all the packages installed in this virtual environment.

One annoyance is VS Code doesn't 'remember' that this is the kernel I want for this project, so I have to select the kernel each time I open this project. I'm sure there's a solution for this, but I'll have to look for that later.